# Converting LaTeX with citations to MediaWiki

Tags: bibliographies, conversion

I would like to convert my LaTeX paper to MediaWiki format in order to contribute parts of it to Wikipedia. The main difficulty is the citations. Here is a MWE LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Over twenty years ago, \cite{McAfee1992Dominant} introduced the first
double auction mechanism.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

And the matching BibTeX file:

```
@article{McAfee1992Dominant,
    author = {McAfee, R. Preston},
    title = {{A dominant strategy double auction}},
    year = {1992}
}
```

The expected result should be something like this:

```
Over twenty years ago, McAfee<ref>{{Cite journal|author=R. Preston McAfee|title=A dominant strategy double auction|year=1992}}</ref> introduced the first double auction mechanism.
```

I tried to do the conversion using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/):

```
pandoc -f latex -t mediawiki mwe.tex > mwe.wiki
```

But the citation did not appear in the result:

```
Over twenty years ago,  introduced the first double auction mechanism.
```

So I guess Pandoc does not support this kind of conversion.

Is there another tool/editor that can be used for this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tex4ht` with suitable configuration. I would use `biblatex` instead of `natbib`, because it gives us access to bibliographic fields. Your modified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello world}

\subsection{Hello, hello}

Over \textit{twenty years} ago, \cite{McAfee1992Dominant} \textbf{introduced} the first
double auction mechanism.

\end{document}
```

I've added some more commands to illustrate my configuration examples. You can use following configuration for such file, named `hello.cfg` for example:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% remove html structure
\Configure{HTML}{}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{BODY}{}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{}
\Configure{HEAD}{}{}
\Configure{TITLE}{}{}
\Configure{VERSION}{}

\newcommand\starttag[1]{\NoFonts\HCode{#1}}
\newcommand\stoptag[1]{\NoFonts\HCode{#1}}
\newcommand\ConfigureInlinetag[2]{%
  \Configure{#1}{\starttag{#2}}{\stoptag{#2}}%
}

\ConfigureInlinetag{textit}{''}
\ConfigureInlinetag{textbf}{'''}

\newcommand\ConfigureSection[2]{%
  \Configure{#1}{}{}{\starttag{#2}}{\stoptag{#2\Hnewline}}%
}

\ConfigureSection{section}{==}
\ConfigureSection{likesection}{==}
\ConfigureSection{subsection}{===}
\ConfigureSection{likesubsection}{===}

% remove section id
\def\gobbleone#1#2{}
\Configure{toTocLink}{\gobbleone}{}

% remove <p> elements
\Configure{HtmlPar}{}{}{\HCode{\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{entrytype}{Cite journal}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecite}{{title=#1}}%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{yearcite}{{year={#1}}}%
\DeclareNameFormat*{labelname}{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{#1}{}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%
  {\printnames{labelname}\HCode{<ref>}\{\{}%
  {%
  \printfield{entrytype}
  \setunit{|}%
  \printtext{author=}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{|}%
  \printfield[titlecite]{title}%
  \setunit{|}%
  \printfield[yearcite]{year}%
  }%
  {}%
  {\}\}\HCode{</ref>}}%

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

there are some interesting things:

```
% remove html structure
\Configure{HTML}{}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{BODY}{}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{}
\Configure{HEAD}{}{}
\Configure{TITLE}{}{}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
```

with these configuration we remove all `<html><head></head><body>` stuff, so we get only clean text.

We need to configure all used commands which may produce html to produce either nothing, or `mediawiki` formatting. This is illustrated here:

```
\newcommand\starttag[1]{\NoFonts\HCode{#1}}
\newcommand\stoptag[1]{\NoFonts\HCode{#1}}
\newcommand\ConfigureInlinetag[2]{%
  \Configure{#1}{\starttag{#2}}{\stoptag{#2}}%
}

\ConfigureInlinetag{textit}{''}
\ConfigureInlinetag{textbf}{'''}
```

With `\ConfigureInlineTag` we can set `mediawiki` tags for inline elements such as `\textit`. Similar configurations could be provided for section commands:

```
\newcommand\ConfigureSection[2]{%
  \Configure{#1}{}{}{\starttag{#2}}{\stoptag{#2\Hnewline}}%
}

\ConfigureSection{section}{==}
\ConfigureSection{likesection}{==}
\ConfigureSection{subsection}{===}
\ConfigureSection{likesubsection}{===}
```

`likesection` is starred `\section*`.

Most complicated stuff is to configure `\cite` command to produce the output you want:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{entrytype}{Cite journal}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecite}{{title=#1}}%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{yearcite}{{year={#1}}}%
\DeclareNameFormat*{labelname}{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{#1}{}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%
  {\printnames{labelname}\HCode{<ref>}\{\{}%
  {%
  \printfield{entrytype}
  \setunit{|}%
  \printtext{author=}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{|}%
  \printfield[titlecite]{title}%
  \setunit{|}%
  \printfield[yearcite]{year}%
  }%
  {}%
  {\}\}\HCode{</ref>}}%
```

I haven't configured `biblatex` for some time, but this should print inline citation in format you want. Note that you should add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[publication type]{entrytype}{publication info}
```

for each used publication type. Only `article` is supported by default, as I don't know what should be produced for other types.

Compile your document with

```
make4ht -um draft -c hello.cfg filename
biber filename
make4ht -um draft -c hello.cfg filename
```

and you will get:

```
   ==Hello world== 



   ===Hello, hello=== 

   Over ''twenty years'' ago, McAfee<ref>{{Cite journal |author=McAfee, R. Preston|title=A dominant strategy double auction|year=1992}}</ref> '''introduced''' the first double auction mechanism.
```

in `filename.html`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [HandWiki](https://handwiki.org) for creating Wiki articles. It uses MediaWiki but includes a BibTeX manager. This means you simply upload your BibTeX file to HandWiki, and use the same BibTeX key inside HandWiki o reference an article

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the bibliography in order to make it work:

```
pandoc -f latex -t mediawiki --bibliography=mediawiki.bib mediawiki.tex -o  mediawiki.wiki
```

You can also specify a CSL style to format the reference to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc would be the easiest to do that.

> pandoc -f latex -t mediawiki --metadata link-citations --bibliography=bibl.bib --csl=cslstyle.csl test.tex -o test.wiki

`--metadata link-citations` creates hyperlinks with your in-text citations and the bibliography. You can delete this part if not needed.

`bibl.bib` is the file of the bibliography you use

`cslstyle.csl` is the style of citation you want. There are lots of choices that can be downloaded from [editor.citationstyles.org](http://editor.citationstyles.org)

`test.tex` is the file you want to convert from

`test.wiki` is the output file you want

all the files should be in the same folder otherwise locations should be specified

Comment: The main differences are `--metadata link-citations` and `cslstyle.csl`, which enables you to process the citation in the format you want easily.